# How to add an element in a list inside a list in python?

Tags: python, list

Say I have 2 lists:

```
list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]  
a = 6
```

Is there anyway I can put `a` into the spot `list[1][2]`?

Comment: Insert or replace?

Comment: for the program i am writing, i need to add, however i would glad to know how to replace too

Comment: `list[1][2]` is out of range.  `list[1]` has a length of 2, so you would have to use `ppend()`

Comment: Now - I was checking what you meant  - `list[1][2]` is the third element of the 2nd list in the list (named \list`)...

Comment: don't name your list as `list`, that's an inbuilt function in python.

Comment: @RoadRunner okay thanks for the tip! And thanks to everyone else for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can just do:

```
lst[1].append(a)

lst
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To add an element, try:

```
my_list[1].append(a)
```

To replace an element:

```
my_list[1][1] = a  # This will replace 5 by 6 in the second sub-list
```

**Example of append:**

```
>>> my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
>>> a = 6
>>> my_list[1].append(a)
>>> my_list
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

**Example of replace:**

```
>>> my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
>>> a = 6
>>> my_list[1][1] = a
>>> my_list
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 6]]
```

**Note:** You should not use `list` to name your variable, because it would replace the built-in type `list`.

Comment: Thank you! I as gonna go look to how to replace elements just now!

Comment: @Badmephisto You're welcome, I added also some examples that you can use to understand better!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `list=[[1,2,3],[4,5]]` (since list is a function in python) let's have

```
l=[[1,2,3],[4,5]]
```

Now there is no `l[1][2]` as yet.
If we try to access it we get

```
>>> l[1][2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

We can append this element

```
l[1].append(a)
```

Now we can access it

```
>>> l[1][2]
6
```

and we can change it:

```
>>> l[1][2] = 44
>>> l
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 44]]
```